# Applet - Drag and Drop - Multiple drop zones in the same Applet

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, applet

I have a working Applet (implements DropTargetListener).
The applet enables drag-drop of files from desktop into the browser - applet embedded.
Can I have multiple drop targets in a single Applet with their own drop() to handle the events?
The best I could do is to have to applet zones from two different Applet classes packaged in a single.jar.
Any input on creating multiple containers for `drop()` listeners would be appreciated.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And please don't post code in comments, add it as an edit to the question, using code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Add the listeners to the components in the applet, rather than the applet itself.

Comment: `public class MyApplet extends Applet implements DropTargetListener{

private Container _container;

public void init()
{
_dropZone1 = new JLabel("Drop files here");
new DropTarget(_dropZone1, this);
_container.add(_dropZone1);
}

public void drop() {
}

}`

1.how do I add a listener for the JLabel named _dropZone1 so that it has it's own listener event that triggers a separate drop()
2.how does it fit into the _container?